# how to show specific number of elements per line?

Tags: c++

Hello everybody here's a question i am trying to solve

Write a C++ program that allows the user to enter a number and then generate its multiplication table,formatting it into 5 columns and 20 lines.
Interaction with the program should look like this(Only the first 4 lines are shown)

```
 Enter a number 7:

 7   14   21   28   35
 42  49  56  63  70
 77  84  91  98  105
```

well here is what i tried

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, mul;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        mul = n * i;
        cout << mul << "\t";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

only the part of 5 columns and 20 lines is left

Comment: Okay so go ahead and complete the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to figure out when to put `\t` and when `\n` after the number. You want to put `\n` after every fifth number, `\t` otherwise.

Hint: there's an arithmetic operator that will help you.

Another solution would be to use a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this?!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,mul;
cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
cin >> n;

for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
    mul=n*i;
    cout << mul << setw(2);
    if(i%5 == 0) // new line after 5 col
     cout << endl;

}


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each line. Within each line loop through each column. At the end of each line print an EOLN character `\n`  signaling the end of the line. If you are new, get some decent C++ book such as [The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840) or read some tutorials.

The setw() function can be use to indicate the width of the "cell" of the table:

```
cout << setw(n) << mul
```

This causes the program to ensure the output is at least n in length by adding trailing spaces if the output is not long enough. However, it has no effect if the length of the output is larger than n. To avoid that, n should be the length of the highest mulitple + 1.